# Xamarin SDKを認識しない？

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

SDKマネージャーを起動しようとすると以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示され開けなくなりました。

```
command did not execute successfully due to an unexpected exception
```

SDKのアップデート中にエラーが発生し強制的に終了してからこのような症状が続いています。
どのように解決すればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin SDKではなく、Android SDKで発生しているエラーではないでしょうか？
おそらくリンク先の件と同一現象に見受けられます。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674065/command-did-not-execute-successfully-due-to-an-unexpected-exception-please-chec

リンク先の方法でも解消できると思いますが、一番簡単で確実なのは以下の手順ではないかと思います。（上記手順より少し時間はかかります）

1. コントロールパネル＞プログラムのアンインストールを開いて「Android SDK Tools」を一旦削除する
2. **標準だと**「C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\」にある、SDKを一旦フォルダごと全部削除する
3. Android SDKを以下ダウンロードしてインストールして単独でインストールし再設定する

3.については、こちらが参考になると思うので良かったら見てみてください。
http://qiita.com/Nuits/items/8454bd523f9afba669a4